# apache-camel put bulk messages into JMS

Tags: xml, apache-camel, jms

Am setting up a project where bulk commit of JMS has to be done in a single shot. Using the transaction for restarting the message processing, so need thoughts on how to push "x" number of messages onto a JMS Queue and do JMS commit.

What am currently doing is creating a JMS message which a long string appended with the message which I wish to commit in one shot.
Then use a Splitter to split the message into multiple in another route. 
Finally, use another route to send the messages onto JMS (as a bulk commit).

```
    <route>
        <from uri="file:sample"/>
        <split streaming="true">
            <tokenize token="\n"/>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:dest"/>
        </split>
    </route>
```

I wish to construct a route that controls when the JMS commit is issued.

The use case is am trying to read a message from Queue A and create many messages (let that number be "x"). And push them to Queue B. However, I wish to do a bulk commit (or batch commit) like DB. Am trying to be efficient not to create connections to JMS and do individual commits.

Comment: So, you want to start a transaction, send multiple messages, and then do a single commit. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is my exact requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully see your problem. Perhaps it is just a matter of what error handling to use.

Setup: You have a Camel route with a **transacted JMS consumer** and in this route you send **multiple messages to one or different queues**.

Good case: The route is successfully completed and all JMS messages are delivered.

Error case: If your route encounters an **error**, let's say in the middle of processing, **some JMS messages are already "sent", some are not**.

In this case **no messages are sent at all** because Camel does a rollback and the already "sent" JMS messages are not really sent or, to be more precise, they are **not yet committed** and they will not get committed.

Important detail: **Camel must not handle the error**. If it does, the error is not propagated to the broker and therefore the consumed message is committed and so is the JMS transaction.

Comment: The first route consumes from Queue A and created multiple messages and pushes them to Route B.

Is there is an option available to do a bulk push and commit; am not ready to open x number of connections to JMS and commit the messages one by one.

Comment: Ah, now I see. The JMS send of multiple messages is not in the same route as the consumption of a message from Queue A. The problem here is that you want to span multiple route processings into one transaction. If you would do this in the same route, it should "just work".

Comment: No, wait. In the edited question you write "to Queue B", in your comment you write "to Route B". Which is correct? :-)

Comment: I was using them interchangeably. Am trying to send it to Queue B from Queue A.

Comment: OK, if you do it in 1 Camel route, consume from Queue A and produce to Queue B, it should "just work" as I described it if you use JMS transactions.

Comment: Won't Camel commit each message though? Aldrine wants to start a transaction, send multiple messages, and then do a single commit.

Comment: Ups, sorry @darius-x for not answering for so long. I missed your question. No Camel will not commit every message. All the **produced** messages are held back and committed only when the **consumed** message is committed. When the consumed message is rollbacked, all produced messages are also rolled back. The JMS transaction makes sure that all JMS things are only executed when the "source" message (consumed message) is successfully processed.

Comment: @burki Thanks for the reply. makes total sense. Good to know.